# PowerBuilder .net Web Forms on Chrome, FireFox, Opera

Tags: .net, firefox, google-chrome, powerbuilder, datawindow

I am using PowerBuilder 12.5 to develop a .net Web Forms
I managed to get work on IE, but it did not work on Chrome, FireFox or Opera

the problem is with Drop Down Data Window 
* In Chrome it does not show the list when click on the arrow
* In FireFox ItemChanged Event does not fire!

Is there any way or tool that allows PowerBuilder .net Web Forms work on Chrome, FireFox, Opera ?

Comment: Adding a link to similar related question which the conclusion was that IE is the only supported browser which Sybase does state and it looks that they really meant it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165536/powerbuilder-12-5-web-forms-columns-not-editable-or-lost-tab-order-upon-deploy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is stated by Sybase in the [Web forms FAQ](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1061922), they did not focused much on cross-browser compatibility:

> We are evaluating Firefox and Safari for multi-browser support. Menus was implemented with third-party menu webcontrol that renders menu items as hyperlinks.

Comment: IOW (from the FAQ above): "it only works on Internet Explorer". No work arounds I've heard of. AFAIK and IMHO, the best PB cross-browser solution is still HTML DataWindows, which isn't a full solution, but still let's you leverage the strongest part of your PB app pretty well.